# Windows Server 2012 Essentials - Trying to setup "Anywhere Access" but the "Computer Access" list for users is blank

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have a new installation of Windows Server 2012 Essentials and I'm trying to setup "Anywhere Access" for both VPN and remote desktop.

The basic setup is all working. Shared folders is working but remote desktop has no computers available.

On the server, if I edit a user with the Essentials Dashboard and go to "Computer access", the list is empty.

The desktop computers have been joined to the domain. I can see them in AD under "Computers".

I think our mistake was that we didn't use the connector tool to join the domain. We moved from a previous domain and went to Computer / Properties, changed the domain and started with a new profile.

Is there something I can do now to make these desktops available for remote desktop?

I can access a desktop directly no problem by going directly to it with the RDP client on port 3389. I do that from the outside world through an SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, it is related to the fact that we didn't use the connector tool.

I removed one computer from the domain (added it to a temporary workgroup) then used the connector tool to rejoin the domain and that computer now appears in the list. More significanty, I guess, it now appears in "Devices" in the dashboard.

The nice thing is that by doing this, it did not build a new profile.

When I look at the deleted and re-added computer in AD, I can't see what's changed.